# Additional field shows up outside table in admin change_list view

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model called `Project` in an app called `projects` that I registered with the admin site so the instances can be added/edited/etc. This works as expected. Now I want to add a button for each project in the change list view on the admin site, that links to a custom form that requires a `Project` instance to do things. I followed a bunch of different tutorials to customize the admin site and managed to add another field to the table of the change list view. However the entries show up outside the table (see image).
[image: Broken table format of admin change list view]

I added the custom field by overwriting the `admin/change_list.html` template and calling a custom template tag `custom_result_list` within it. This tag adds a table field to the change list and then calls the `admin/change_list_results.html` template to render it. I have confirmed with a debugger that the item is added to the entries of the change list before the template is rendered (see image).[image: list of variables in a debug window]

I cannot explain why the table is not rendered correctly even though the additional field has the same structure as the auto-generated ones. I have to admit I have resorted to Cargo Cult Programming, because I do not understand how this is supposed to work, despite spending too many hours trying to solve this simple problem.

Here's the relevant code.

In file `/projects/templatetags/custom_admin_tags.py`:

```py
from django import template
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import result_list as admin_result_list

def custom_result_list(chl):
    extended_cl = {}
    extended_cl.update(admin_result_list(chl))

    extended_cl["result_headers"].append({
        'class_attrib': r' class="column-__str__"',
        'sortable': False,
        'text': 'Configure Project'
    })

    idx = 0
    snippet = '<td class="action-button"><a href="/admin/projects/project_admin/{}">{}</a></td>'
    for project in chl.result_list:
        extended_cl["results"][idx].append(snippet.format(project.id, project.unmod_name))
        idx += 1
    return extended_cl

register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag('admin/change_list_results.html')(custom_result_list)
```

In file `templates/admin/projects/project/change_list.html`:

```py
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}
{% load custom_admin_tags %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    {% custom_result_list cl %}
    {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To fix your issue:

`from django.utils.html import format_html`

replace your `snippet.format(...)` with `format_html(snippet,...)`

#### Explanation:

in django, all strings you pass from python are automatically HTML escaped. which here means, all your tags will not be considered as HTML. Such limitation is added to avoid any potential exploits by hackers. In your case, use of a template to render html is highly recommended. However, you can also send raw html from python using [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) helper function.